# How to copy formulas when there are empty rows in between without losing the sequence of linked sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an excel file which has two sheets.

- Summary
- RawData

My Summary sheet has data like this where is there is a gap of few rows for every next data row

[image: Screenshot of the example data]

Now the problem is if I have a sheet with 1000+ rows and I want to change anything in it, I have to manually edit each cell reference as it does not continue the reference of the RawData sheet but get the cell number as the reference of Summary sheet.

In the Example picture attached, if I copy and paste the formula, I get the cell numbers as 2, 5, 8, 11 and so on depending on the row gap where as I need to copy the formulas as shown in the manual formula column like B2, B3, B4, B5 sequence regardless of the current sheet row number. Tried many things but couldn't find any solution at all. Any help?

To avoid confusion, creating more realistic example from my sheet with a screenshot of RawData tab as well.

**RawData Sheet:-**
[RawData Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sw77.png)

Here is the linked sheet where i am linking data from RawData sheet
[Summary Product Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCxct.png)

As you can see, It is showing Test Product 1, Test Product 6 and Test Product 11 if you will copy paste the formula whereas this should be Test Product 1, 2 and 3.

Here is the example excel file link https://we.tl/t-3F3mJra7pe

Comment: Bit confused,, you mean to say that whether you write Formula Manually or Copy it returns Formula insted od the Result!!

Comment: No, I cannot copy formula in the same sequence of linked Sheet if there are empty rows.

Comment: ,, with attached screen shot in both cases Formula looks correct,, now write me whether are returning result or not? Or returns Formula itself!!

Comment: It is returning results but Manual Formula is returning correct one which is tedious job if you have to update thousands of rows, the 2nd copy paste column is bringing wrong records as you can see its skipping numbers and mapping B5 column whereas it should be B3.

Comment: ,, when you copy Formula it never use Sheet Name this happens when you type Formula and either include cell references by typing or selecting through Mouse!!

Comment: I just updated the section above and also provided the example excel sheet linke https://we.tl/t-3F3mJra7pe

Comment: ,, wait let me check the File!!

Comment: ,, both Formula simply has cell reference along with sheet ,,, as you said Copied has got Wrong sequence, but I'm unable to understand what did you copied,, if you copy A3 Cell from Raw Data Sheet will return Value not the Formula as I found in the Sheet (Red Area) ,, what I got happens when you type `=` then move to `Raw Data` sheet and Click cell `A3` & press Enter!!

Comment: to complete the sequence, I need results till product 11. Try this. Select B18 till F22 and paste it in B23 to copy next product and see what product name this will return? If you will repeat this, It will never give you Product 1, Product 2, Product 3 so on It always copy the formula and say my first A1 cell has a value of =RawData!B2 leave 6 rows empty and paste next value to A8 Cell, the formula here will become =RawData!B9 now this should be B2 not 9 really cant explain further to this

Comment: ,,it's natural since Row interval between `F3` and `F8` is `6` including `F3`,, simply drag Formula from `F3` to `F8` you find the Sequence!!

Comment: Bro, You are not getting the problem at all. I know how to drag to paste. I dont want to copy formula in middle 6 empty rows. I want to copy formula every after 6 rows so your drag will never work. Anyway, will wait for someone else to answer

Comment: I got the issue and just for your understanding I've suggest you to Drag the Formula will make the picture clear that How & Why you are getting wrong sequence!!

Comment: ,, I got the solution,, ☺

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: ,, now check the post for the solution!!

Answer (score 1):

Let me first describe the reason behind the issue,

- On **Summary Sheet** in Cell `F3` the Formula is `=Rawdata!A2`returns value `Test Product 1`.
- As soon you copy **Summary Sheet's** data from  `B3:F7` at `B8`,  Excel Reads **6 Rows** between `F3:F8` and returns  `Test Product 7` from  Cell `B8` of **RawData** Sheet.

*Which was spoiling the whole exercise.*

**The Solution:**

- You need **Helper Column** in **RawData** Sheet.

[image]

- Re-write Cell `B3` in **Summary** Sheet with 
  **Simple Product 1**.
- Enter this Formula in Cell `F3` in **Summary** Sheet.

`=VLOOKUP(B3,RawData!A$2:E$12,2,FALSE)`

*You get this.*

[image]

- Now, **Copy** Range `B3:F7` and **Paste** on Cell `B8`.

*You get this.*

[image]

- Re-write Cell `B8` with **Simple Product 2**, now you get the correct sequence.

[image]

- Repeat the **Copy & Paste** with correcting **Simple Product's** sequence, you get desire 
  results.

**You may adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.**

Answer (score 1):

In these type of scenarios, I think a simpler yet robust solution would be using OFFSET() function.
Offset returns a reference to a single cell or a range of cells.
Considering your scenario, if first Formula Copy&Paste should refers RawData Product1, and 2nd Copy&Paste would refers to Product2, no matter how many rows would be skipped on these Copy&Pastes, I would implement this OFFSET as below:

```
A B               C      D        E       F
  Simple Product  FALSE  TRUE             =OFFSET(RawData!$A$1;COUNTA(Summary!$B$1:B1);0)
                  AttrId AttrName AttrVal
                  1      Size     Small
                  1      Size     Medium
                  1      Size     Large
  Simple Product  FALSE  TRUE             =OFFSET(RawData!$A$1;COUNTA(Summary!$B$1:B6);0)
                  AttrId AttrName AttrVal
                  1      Size     Small
                  1      Size     Medium
                  1      Size     Large
  Simple Product  FALSE  TRUE             =OFFSET(RawData!$A$1;COUNTA(Summary!$B$1:B11);0)
                  AttrId AttrName AttrVal
                  1      Size     Small
                  1      Size     Medium
                  1      Size     Large
  Simple Product  FALSE  TRUE             =OFFSET(RawData!$A$1;COUNTA(Summary!$B$1:B16);0)
                  AttrId AttrName AttrVal
                  1      Size     Small
                  1      Size     Medium
                  1      Size     Large
```

Notice that when you copy the formula "=OFFSET(RawData!$A$1;COUNTA(Summary!$B$1:B1);0)", the reference to "Summary!$B$1:B1" will automatically change with the same behavior that you DO NOT WANT; but, once that reference is being used inside a COUNTA() formula, it will to the trick, and you will not have to change thousands of references by yourself.
Doing this, COUNTA() will count how many times a "Simple Product" is appearing since the start of the column, and will use this inside offset to refer to the respective product in ordinal position. All of this without the need of creating auxiliary columns.
The result will be as follows:

```
A B               C      D        E       F
  Simple Product  FALSE  TRUE             TestProduct1
                  AttrId AttrName AttrVal
                  1      Size     Small
                  1      Size     Medium
                  1      Size     Large
  Simple Product  FALSE  TRUE             TestProduct2
                  AttrId AttrName AttrVal
                  1      Size     Small
                  1      Size     Medium
                  1      Size     Large
  Simple Product  FALSE  TRUE             TestProduct3
                  AttrId AttrName AttrVal
                  1      Size     Small
                  1      Size     Medium
                  1      Size     Large
  Simple Product  FALSE  TRUE             TestProduct4
                  AttrId AttrName AttrVal
                  1      Size     Small
                  1      Size     Medium
                  1      Size     Large
```